# Extract partial string from a dataframe column with many text elements (without Regex)

Tags: r, string, mapping, match, partial

I have a dataframe with a column full of text. It's hard to find any Regex pattern in it. What I am interested in though is to extract all countries based on a predefined list of countries I already have. I figured it shouldn't be too hard, but cannot find my way around str_extract to do this

Here's a replicable example:

```
data <- data.frame (text_column = c("I travelled to Germany last year, afterwards I visited Poland"," I enjoyed my vacation in Spain", "The weather in the Netherlands was not great"))
```

And I have a list of countries

```
country_vector <- c("Germany", "Poland","the Netherlands","France")
```

What I want is to match the text column against those countries, extract all matches and pivot them into separate columns for all matches. If no match, then we can enter NA.

So the expected outcome for this is:

```
Country_1         Country_2 
Germany           Poland
NA                NA 
the Netherlands   NA
```

Given that there can be a multitude of countries mentioned in one column the ncol of the final tibble/df needs to be the length of the entry with the maximum number of countries.

Any idea how to tackle this? I've been able to do it for 1 entry but not for my entire dataframe. But I have the feeling I'm working in the wrong direction and there must be an easier solution.

```
temp <- stringr::str_extract(data$text_column,country_vector) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>%
  magrittr: set_colnames(c("countries")) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(!is.na(countries)) 

if (nrow(temp==0)){
  temp <- temp %>% add_row(countries = NA) %>% 
    mutate(order = paste0("country_",seq(1:nrow(.)))) %>% 
    pivot_wider(.,names_from = order,values_from = countries)
  print(temp)
} else {
  temp <- temp %>% 
    mutate(order = paste0("country_",seq(1:nrow(.)))) %>% 
    pivot_wider(.,names_from = order,values_from = countries)
  print(temp)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`str_extract_all` gives the data that you want :

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(data$text_column, str_c(country_vector, collapse = '|'))

#[[1]]
#[1] "Germany" "Poland" 

#[[2]]
#character(0)

#[[3]]
#[1] "the Netherlands"
```

To get the data in the format that you want you need to manipulate the above output.

```
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(lapply(
       str_extract_all(data$text_column, str_c(country_vector, collapse = '|')), 
        function(x) if(length(x)) as.data.frame(t(x)) else as.data.frame(t(NA))))

#               V1     V2
#1         Germany Poland
#2            <NA>   <NA>
#3 the Netherlands   <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a `simplify` option in `str_extract_all`, which returns a `matrix`.  So, we can directly convert to a two column `matrix` and wrap with `as.data.frame` (if a data.frame is needed)

```
library(stringr)
as.data.frame(str_extract_all(data$text_column, 
      str_c(country_vector, collapse = '|'), simplify = TRUE))
#               V1     V2
#1         Germany Poland
#2                       
#3 the Netherlands
```